# Temporary oil pan leak fix?

Tags: oil-pan

I have a small crack in my oil pan, I have ordered the new one but it will take a few days to come in. Is there a to band aid it temporarily until the new one arrives and is installed?

Comment: A photo of where the crack is would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the pan off, clean and dry there's a few things you can try, depending on the size and shape of the crack. Keep in mind all of these must be on the outside of your pan, not the inside, the last thing you want is for any of this to get into your engine:

- Waterproof, heat resistant tape: okay, duct tape. Yes, it fixes everything, but in this case only the good stuff that will do. It is ready to go as soon as it is stuck on. One benefit is there's no chance of it getting through the crack into the oil
- High temperature silicone sealant: this stuff works wonders as a temporary repair, although I've never tried it with an oil pan crack before. It needs hours to cure, so it's not an instant fix
- Solder: If it's a small leak solder may patch it up temporarily
- Epoxy glue: this is sometimes called coldweld, and the method I would use. It's a 2 part resin and curing agent which you mix together and then apply. There's different varieties with different cure times, some of which will be fully cured in 1 hour, I'd go for a bit longer than that as it gives you more time to work with it. Epoxy is extremely strong, some would consider this a permanent fix rather than replacing the pan, but I'd still replace the pan personally. I sometimes reinforce a fix using nylon mesh tape, applying the epoxy over a wider area

Keep in mind none of these may be suitable depending on the size and shape of the crack.

Comment: Name brand "duck" tape or gorilla tape?

Comment: Doesn't have to be @TBarnett, it just needs to say high temperature on the label.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some cracks that were drilled, threaded and bolts put in - takes careful work and they need to overlap. Can also be welded.

But usually means it has to be removed.

May be easier just to wait as the labor required is usually significant.